# React - Manage Bootstrap Modals in components

Tags: reactjs

I have a ReactJS app with 4 screens/components. Each screen can link to another one.

I want to use Modals to display content of each screen, this way I don't lose the state of the current screen.

For now I just set the Modal on my 1st component :

```
<Modal show={this.state.show}
       ref={this.ModalGlobal}
       onHide={() => this.setState({show: false})}
>
    <Modal.Body>
        {this.state.id &&
        <MyComponentB id={this.state.id} />
        }
    </Modal.Body>
</Modal>
```

On my ComponentB, I want to open the same Modal with different ID.

I tried to use references, but I don't know what to do with that in my ComponentB ?

Like :

```
this.ModalGlobal.current.destroy
```

Do I have to use Redux or can it be done using contexts or other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having one modal close another one and open that one, would it be possible to instead have the modal update its own contents based on the ID? You could make a wrapper for the modal that will update the body of the modal depending on the current ID. Something like this:

```
const MyModal = ({id}) => {
  const [modalPage, setModalPage] = useState(id);
  const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setModalPage(id)
  }, [id]);

  const openModal = async () => {
    setModalIsOpen(true);
    document.body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
  }

  const closeModal = () => {
    setModalIsOpen(false);
    document.body.style.overflowY = "";
  }

  const modalPages = {
    'welcome': <WelcomeComponent setModalPage />,
    'products': <ProductsComponent setModalPage />,
    'contact': <ContactComponent setModalPage />
  }

  const content = modalPages[modalPage];

  return (
    <Modal
      isOpen={modalIsOpen}
      onRequestClose={closeModal}
      className="react-modal"
      overlayClassName="react-modal-overlay"
    >
      {content}
    </Modal>
  );
}
```